# Unable to identify element inside shadow-root in ReactJS application

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, shadow-dom, facebook-debugger

ReactJS application is not allowing to find the element inside shadow-root.

I could able to access the element using /deep/ in my AngularJS application but This is not working with React application.

[image]

We are able to find the elements till `$("#root .px-app-nav")` this point

Comment: Please include a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

I Found the solution. If you have any shadow-root then use `elementPath.shadowRoot.querySelector(element)`.

`$('#root px-app-nave').shadowRoot.querySelector('.app-nav')`